# Is the following sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Need a help to know if the following sentence is right:

> I tested it a few times.

Comment: "not with all the letters in lowercase" is potentially ambiguous or confusing.  I would spell that out more precisely if I was you.  For example do you mean that it only works when none of the letters are lowercase?  Or do you mean that it **doesn't** work when all the letters are lowercase?  or something else?

Comment: Hi @MaxWilliams - It works like this 'DoThisTask' and doesnt works when we use 'dothistask'. This is what I need to convey.

Comment: Then I would say "It only works when it contains at least one uppercase character", or "It doesn't work if all the characters are lowercase".  Saying "as below" is also to be avoided unless you mean to say "It only works when I use **this exact string of characters**.  "

Answer (score 1):

The only definite mistake is using "ran" instead of the participle "run". However, a sentence like that needs commas. I'd suggest this:

> "I tested it a few times, and for some reason it seems to be working only when run as below, and not with all the letters in lowercase."

Usually, we'd put commas around "for some reason" too, but that would be too much. Better to split the sentence:

> "I tested it a few times. For some reason, it seems to be working only when run as below, and not with all the letters in lowercase."

Comment: If you answer questions which are blatantly off-topic, you do have the opportunity to gain rep. But that will be removed when the question is deleted, **and** it gives askers the wrong idea about questions which can be asked.